# Build successful but unable to run on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, cordova

I am making a demo of cordova app. The console log is showing me build successful but after sometime it shows this error and run fails :

> 2016-07-30 09:34:47.609 instruments[9268:1431174] WebKit Threading
>   Violation - initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread. Instruments
>   Usage Error: Unknown device specified:
>   "B7257830-92A2-4C85-A4BA-342D7237F9A8"
>
> Known Devices:
>
> test's iPhone (8.4.1) [7fdfcc5aaeb179fdb53a86343ba18796a1825bc4]

The error is to replace UDID with known devices but I am unable find the file where it is mentioned.

Please share the path of file or file name or anything related to this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread." That's pretty clear. What more do you want to know?

Comment: Where to chage UDID ? It is given static in some file for example purpose.

Comment: @idan-adar Why did you vandalize his question? You removed tags that were vital to the answer.

Comment: Please choose your words wisely. I did not "vandalize" anything. At the time I did not find the question relevant to mobilefirst.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solved this error simply following two steps.**

**Step 1:** Go to Run Options and select Run Configuration as image shown below.

[image]

**Step 2 :** Now a window will open as shown below & select your device from simulator list.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, that's eclipse.  Your question made no mention of eclipse.

Comment: That's Eclipse and yet the solution is not related to Eclipse but to a plug-in being run in Eclipse. There is no problem in Eclipse.

Comment: @IdanAdar I am not bleming you dude I just told him ! I got my solution that's it. anyways thanx for your efforts :)